# setImeActionLabel or setImeOptions not work, i always have caption "DONE" on the return key

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-softkeyboard, android-virtual-keyboard

I have an EditText and I try to change the caption of the return key show on the virtual keyboard like this :

```
editText.setSingleLine;
editText.setImeActionLabel("GO", IME_ACTION_GO);
editText.setImeOptions(IME_ACTION_GO);
```

But strangely i have always the caption "DONE" ?

What did i miss ?

Comment: Did you try in xml? android:imeOptions

Comment: no, i can't because i create the editText dynamically  ...

Comment: try this mEditText.setImeActionLabel("Custom text", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);

Comment: not work :( i still have the text : "done" :(